# tensor $k[x] \otimes_k k[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I am thinking about tensor product $k[x] \otimes_k k[x]$.

I know that $k[x] \otimes_k k[y] \cong k[x,y]$, but what about $k[x] \otimes_k k[x]$?

As far as I understand I can't say that $k[x] \otimes_k k[x] \cong k[x]$.

That's because for the map 
$\phi:k[x] \otimes_k k[x]\rightarrow k[x]$
which maps $a\otimes b\mapsto ab$, we have $\ker(\phi)$ is not zero, so $\phi$ is not injective.

Hence,  $k[x] \otimes_k k[x] \not\cong k[x]$.

Am I right? Is $k[x] \otimes_k k[x]$ isomorphic to something?

I got stuck here, and have no ideas how to construct the space isomorphic to the given above.

Any hints are welcome! Thank you!

**P.S.: This is not duplicate of other questions in MathStackExchange, since those questions consider the space isomorphic to the tensor product $k[x] \otimes_k k[y]$**

Comment: $k[x]$ is isomorphic to $k[y]$, so you can just substitute $k[y]$ in the latter term.

Comment: If you want to express an isomorphism using a bilinear pairing without substituting the isomorphic copy in, consider $\phi: k[x] \otimes_k k[x] \to k[y,z]$ given by $a(x) \otimes b(x) \mapsto a(y)b(z)$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein hence $k[x] \otimes_k k[x] \cong k[x] \otimes_k k[y] \cong k[x,y]$, am I right?

Comment: Exactly. ${}{}{}$

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Got it! Thank you very much!